# Reusing Object does not work properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5, code-reuse

I'm reusing a created Object just to change a Date and the ordinal value, but at the end I get 6 objects exactly as the last.

in other words, I'm adding the object as a **Reference** and I should add as a **Value**

What should I inherit my Object to have the `Copy()` method ?

```
RecurringPayment rp, copy;

rp = new RecurringPayment
{
    ...
}
payments.Add(rp);  // add first object

copy = rp;  // Copy the original element
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    copy.NextPaymentDate = copy.NextPaymentDate.AddDays(copy.RecurringTime * 7);
    copy.OrderOrdinal = copy.OrderOrdinal + 1;

    payments.Add(copy); // add 5 more with X weeks ahead
}
```

Thank you

Comment: By the way your comments in your code does not say much. That the method "Add" adds an object is not something you need to comment. Perhaps comment why you added it etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement ICloneable and then call clone to get a shallow copy of your object!

You can implement like this if you want(there are probably better ways out there):

```
public object Clone()
{
    return MemberwiseClone();
}
```

Comment: That's the easiest one :) Ty!

Answer (score 2):

You don't end up with 6 *objects*. You end up with 6 *references* all of which refer to the same single *object*.

You *could* implement `ICloneable`, and call `Object.MemberwiseClone` - but I'm not sure I would. Instead, I'd be tempted to try to make RecurringPayment immutable to start with, and add a method `WithNextPaymentDate(DateTime nextDate)` or something similar, which creates a new object with the given values. Your code would then be something like this:

```
// Can't use object initializers on immutable types of course - all the
// values would have to be specified in the constructor call
RecurringPayment payment = new RecurringPayment(...);
payments.Add(payment);

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    // This would automatically increment the OrderOrdinal in the newly
    // created object
    payment = payment.WithNextPaymentDate(payment.RecurringTime * 7);
    payments.Add(payment);
}
```

Comment: wonder why you wouldn't choose the Clone() approach, any technical worry or was just to provide a new insight? Ty.

Comment: @balexandre: I find immutable types easier to understand and work with. `ICloneable` is generally regarded as a bad interface: you have to cast the result as it returns just `object`, and there's no indication about whether it should perform a deep or shallow clone.

Comment: I will follow your recommendation :)